# How do I show recently entered textbox value in Chrome and Firefox also IE?

Tags: php, html

I want to  show recently entered values when I click the textbox.  How do I do it in Firefox and Chrome also IE?

Comment: What do you mean? Reload the inputs with previously entered content (in case user comes back to the form) or do you mean the browser autocomplete feature?

Comment: i got alraedy the username and password from user and i stored in my database.  i want to show all the matching or recentlly entered username.from database.

Comment: As Ashkan says, it's the browser that does that, not the page that you write. Also, showing valid recently used usernames is a massive security hole.  For a hacker, finding a valid username is half the battle. Your site will soon be pwned.

Answer (score 0):

most of the major browsers has autocomplete function, that shows the recently entered usernames (emails, ...) however user may disable the autocomplete function.

however if you want to be able to show autocomplete in all cases, you must save the recently entered usernames or whatever you want in cookies (as they must be saved on the client computer). you can use one of the many autocomplete plugins for jquery that are already written to show the data stored in cookies.